# Self captured by a closure before all members were initialized

Tags: swift, swift3, core-location

My ViewController looks like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

... (Optional Variables declared)

var geoLoc: CLLocationCoordinate2D?

override func viewDidLoad() {
... (Optional Variables initialized)
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(addressString) { (placemarks, error) in
            self.geoLoc = placemarks?[0].location?.coordinate
        }

}

}
```

and I am getting this error:

```
'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized
```

I have tried many dead-end workarounds, but simply cannot find the cause of the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: What other properties have you created in your ViewController? All the properties of class must be initialized before you can use self anywhere in the class.

Comment: This doesn't look like where you should be getting this error. Are you sure this code isn't in `init`? Have you implemented a custom `init`? Is this really where the error is coming up? It's strange to see this error in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: It's an odd behavior. Swift should output the error message: _'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized_ only in an initializer. Seems you have omitted too much. (For example, your class lacks `: UIViewController`.) Please show more code which can reproduce your issue.

Comment: @OOPer It seems the issue was that Xcode viewed my other variables as non-initialized (even though they were initialized above this code) so it would not let me use the `self` prefix on the class. The fix to this was giving my variables default values.

Comment: Thanks for reporting. If you could include enough code to reproduce in your question, the report would be more valuable for much more developers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you have some variables in your class that are only declared, but not initialized by the time your capture is called, where you are referring to `self`.

Declaring a variable: `var a: Int` and initializing it: `var a:Int = 0` or `var a:Int? = nil` are not the same.

All variables of your class need to be initialized (given an initial value) before you could refer to `self`.